# How to read header values of a csv file using getHeaders() method in CsvReader

Tags: java, opencsv

I have written code as below. But it is returning null

```
CsvReader headerNames = new CsvReader(filePath);
String[] names = headerNames.getHeaders();
```

Comment: can you show the file you are reading

Answer (score 0):

```
String file = "fileName.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file ));
// if the first line is the header
String[] header = reader.readNext();
```

Comment: Instead addition to your code fragment, would you please provide some explanation and perhaps a reference to the documentation? It would make your answer more helpful. Further, since there is more than one source for CSV + Reader, could you cite which library you used?

Answer (score 0):

***Please use this code inside try catch block or Throws IOException***

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("emps.csv"), ',');  
            // read line by line
            String[] record = null;

            while ((record = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.print(record[0]);
                System.out.print(record[1]);
            }
           reader.close();
```

***Or You can Try This Way***

```
public class OpenCSVReaderReadAllExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("emps.csv"), ',');

        List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();

        Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String[] record = iterator.next();
            System.out.print(record[0]);
            System.out.print(record[0]);
        }
        reader.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code , it will give you the header's Name.

```
`Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filepath));`
```

`CSVReader headerNames = new CSVReader(reader);`
`String[] names = headerNames.readNext();`
 `for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++)`
 `{`
`System.out.println(names[i]);`
`}`